# SkiaSharp load imge from ImageView

Tags: android, skiasharp

I am trying to load bitmap from ImageView to SKCanvasView.
The problem is that this image has CenterCrop set and image that was loaded to canvas is way too big. How to make it look exactly like in ImageView?

Code samples:

```
_skBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)_frontView.ImageView.Drawable).Bitmap.ToSKBitmap();
```

And drawing:

```
private void _canvas_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

        var scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

        canvas.Scale(scale);

        if (_skBitmap != null)
        {
            canvas.DrawBitmap(_skBitmap, e.Info.Rect);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested (in my case image is always wider then screen):

```
private void _canvas_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

    var scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

    canvas.Scale(scale);

    if (_skBitmap != null)
        {
            var factor = scaledSize.Height / _skBitmap.Height;
            var nw = _skBitmap.Width * factor;
            var offset = (scaledSize.Width - nw) / 2;

            var sr = new SKRect(offset, 0, nw + offset, scaledSize.Height);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(_skBitmap, sr);
        }
}
```